# Use first query's value in second query's value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
+---------+----------+
| post_id |   path   |
+---------+----------+
|       1 | 1/       |
|       2 | 1/2/     |
|       3 | 1/2/3/   |
|       4 | 1/2/3/4/ |
|       5 | 1/2/5/   |
+---------+----------+
```

I then have a query that looks something like the following:

```
SELECT post_id AS column_1,
       post_path
FROM posts
WHERE post_path REGEXP concat(?, '/[0-9]+/$') LIMIT 5
UNION
SELECT post_id AS column_2,
       post_path
FROM posts
WHERE post_path REGEXP concat(?, '/', column_1, '/[0-9]+/$') LIMIT 5
```

On the last line, you'll see that I'm using `column_1` to refer to the `post_id` from the first query, however, this doesn't work.

How can I make this work such that I can use the `post_id` from the first query in the second query where `column_1` is currently located?

Thanks.

Comment: Please explain what you want this query to do.  You might be surprised to learn that non-working code often doesn't fully express one's intentions.

Comment: It makes little sense to restrict a UNION in the same manner as a JOIN.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I updated the post (I forgot to include the table template). I'm trying to select the post_id of, first, any result that has a post_path of `X/Y/` and then any result that has the post_path of the form `X/Y/Z/`, where `Y` is the value from the first select query.

Comment: @user4171336 . . . What do you want the query to return, given the sample data in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `@variable_name:=` to use the current data of your selected column, here is the code

```
SELECT @col:=post_id AS column_1,
   post_path
FROM posts
WHERE post_path REGEXP concat(?, '/[0-9]+/$') LIMIT 5
UNION
SELECT post_id AS column_2,
   post_path
FROM posts
WHERE post_path REGEXP concat(?, '/', @col, '/[0-9]+/$') LIMIT 5
```

`@col` as you can see `@col` is your variable, for more definition of `@col` you can visit my other answer here [#1054 - Unknown column in 'field list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26729041/1054-unknown-column-in-field-list/26729292#26729292)